# How to use/set custom keys instead of randomly generated on CryptoPP FHMQV class?

Tags: windows, crypto++

I am using CryptoPP 8.2.

The example in the wiki [Here](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Fully_Hashed_Menezes-Qu-Vanstone) works.
Now i want to send the generated keys over the socket to compute the shared secret on the other end. How would i set the received keys into the FHMQV_Domain class?

```
OID CURVE = secp256r1();
FHMQV_Domain<DL_GroupParameters_EC<ECP>> fhmqvA(CURVE,true); //Client
FHMQV_Domain<DL_GroupParameters_EC<ECP>> fhmqvB(CURVE,false); //Server
```

I have not seen any method inside this class to set custom keys.

```
  SecByteBlock sprivA(fhmqvA.StaticPrivateKeyLength()), spubA(fhmqvA.StaticPublicKeyLength());
  // Party A, ephemeral (temporary) key pair
  SecByteBlock eprivA(fhmqvA.EphemeralPrivateKeyLength()), epubA(fhmqvA.EphemeralPublicKeyLength());

  // Party B, static (long term) key pair
  SecByteBlock sprivB(fhmqvB.StaticPrivateKeyLength()), spubB(fhmqvB.StaticPublicKeyLength());
  // Party B, ephemeral (temporary) key pair
  SecByteBlock eprivB(fhmqvB.EphemeralPrivateKeyLength()), epubB(fhmqvB.EphemeralPublicKeyLength());

  // Imitate a long term (static) key
  fhmqvA.GenerateStaticKeyPair(rng, sprivA, spubA);
  // Ephemeral (temporary) key
  fhmqvA.GenerateEphemeralKeyPair(rng, eprivA, epubA);

  // Imitate a long term (static) key
  fhmqvB.GenerateStaticKeyPair(rng, sprivB, spubB);
  // Ephemeral (temporary) key
  fhmqvB.GenerateEphemeralKeyPair(rng, eprivB, epubB);
```

This only generates random keys. I want to supply them when they are pre known.

in the wiki page it has this function to create a class with **BufferedTransformation** with group parameters and options. But i don't know how to create this or if this is really what i am looking for.

````
◆ FHMQV_Domain() [3/7]
Construct a FHMQV domain.

Parameters

bt  BufferedTransformation with group parameters and options
clientRole  flag indicating initiator or recipient```
````

I am using this function for the class creation

```
◆ FHMQV_Domain() [2/7]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i am going to answer this since i solved it by myself so just in case if someone runs into my issue.

In the example shown in the question, we have to create the **spubB** and **epubB** as `SecByteBlock` with the size of `StaticPublicKeyLength` and `EphemeralPublicKeyLength` respectively.

We can then use `memcpy` to set the **B public static** & the **B public ephemeral** key into their `BytePtr()`.

So for the above example, it would look something like this

```
memcpy(spubB.BytePtr(),(B Static public key's byte array),spubB.SizeInBytes()); //Sets the public static key.
memcpy(epubB.BytePtr(),(B Public ephemeral key's byte array),epubB.SizeInBytes()); //Sets the ephemeral key.
```